# Java covariance

Tags: java, covariance

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. Say I have the following code:

```
class Animal { }
class Mammal extends Animal { }
class Giraffe extends Mammal { }
...
public static List<? extends Mammal> getMammals() { return ...; }
...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Mammal> mammals = getMammals(); // compilation error
}
```

Why does the assignment result in a compilation error? The error is something like:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#4-of ? extends Mammal> to List<Mammal>
```

According to my understanding of covariance, the `getMammals()` method returns a `list` that will always contain `Mammal` objects so it should be assignable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `getMammals` could return a `List<Giraffe>`, and if that was convertable to `List<Mammal>` then you'd be able to add a `Zebra` to it. You can't be allowed to add a `Zebra` to a list of `Giraffe`, can you?

```
class Zebra extends Mammal { }

List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe>();

List<Mammal> mammals = giraffes; // not allowed

mammals.add(new Zebra()); // would add a Zebra to a list of Giraffes
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, it doesn't work like that unfortunately.

When you declare getMammals() to return `List<? extends Mammal>` it means it can return `List<Mammal>` or `List<Giraffe>` but not `List<Animal>`

Yours main() should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? extends Mammal> mammals = getMammals();
    Mammal mammal = mammals.get(0);
}
```

EDIT: Regarding covariance, that's what is usually meant by that:

```
class Animal {
    public Animal getAnimal() {return this;}
}

class Mammal extends Animal {
    public Mammal getAnimal() {return this;}
}

class Giraffe extends Mammal {
    public Giraffe getAnimal() {return this;}
}
```

As you can see it allows to overload return type of methods when you overriding the method.

Comment: + 1, but could you explain what "List or List but not List" means?! :p

Comment: Reformatted to remove the confusing 'List or List but not List' :-)

Comment: The generics were being treated as html, escaped

Comment: I don't understand this answer - the OP doesn't want to treat it as a `List<Animal>`.