# Java: Superclass and subclass

Tags: java, variables, subclass, superclass, class-hierarchy

1. Can a subclass variable be cast to any of its superclasses?
2. Can a superclass variable be assigned any subclass variable?
3. Can a superclass be assigned any variable?
4. If so, can an interface variable be assigned a variable from any implementing class?

Comment: You should make a clear distinction between the concept of a variable and a value. As it is now, your question is very confusing.

Comment: You may want to read up on contra-/covariance, as the answer will change if you slightly change your question. You can get a rough idea where it will be a different answer by reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184295/java-covariance-question

Answer (score 10):

Are all dogs also animals?

Are all animals also dogs?

If you need an animal, and I give you a dog, is that always acceptable?

If you need a dog specifically, but I give you any animal, can that ever be problematic?

If you need something you can drive, but you don't care what it is as long as it has methods like .Accelerate and .Steer, do you care if it's a Porsche or an ambulance?

Answer (score 7):

- Yes
- You can assign a subclass *instance* to a superclass variable
- Huh?
- You can assign an *instance* of a class to a variable of any interface type that the class implements

Comment: I think a superclass cannot be assigned _any_ variable, just one of compatible type.

Comment: The second question is if a *superclass* instance can be assigned to a *subclass* variable, and the answer to that is definitively *no*.

Comment: @Mark: The question is unclear.  I optimistically chose the interpretation that has a positive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of clarity, consider:

```
class A extends B implements C {  }
```

Where `A` is a subclass, `B` is a superclass and `C` is an interface that `A` implements.

1. A subclass can be cast upwards to any superclass.

   ```
   B b = new A();
   ```
2. A superclass cannot be cast downwards to any subclass (this is unreasonable because subclasses might have capabilities a superclass does not). You cannot do:

   ```
   A a = new B(); // invalid!
   ```
3. A superclass can be assigned to any variable of appropriate type.

   ```
   A q = new A(); // sure, any variable q or otherwise...
   ```
4. A class may be assigned to a variable of the type of one of its implemented interfaces.

   ```
   C c = new A();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Can a subclass variable be cast to any
>   of its superclasses?

Yes

> And can a superclass variable be
>   assigned any subclass variable?

Yes

> Can a superclass be assigned any
>   variable?

Yes

> If so, can an interface variable be
>   assigned a variable from any
>   implementing class?

Yes

Comment: you cannot assign a superclass instance to a subclass variable.

Comment: @Mark Perhaps I misunderstood the question.  Does it not say "a superclass variable be assigned a subclass variable"?  e.g. ArrayList myArrayList = ... ; List myList = myArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's usually the main idea behing [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism).

Let's say you have some Shapes: Circle, Square, Triangle. You'd have:

```
class Shape { ... }

class Circle extends Shape { ... }

class Square extends Shape { ... }

class Triangle extends Shape { ... }
```

The idea of inheritance is that a Circle is-a Shape. So you can do:

```
Shape x = ...;
Point p = x.getCenterPosition();
```

You don't need to care about which concrete type the `x` variable is.