# Can I add to a generic collection of type A values of type B ,which extends A, without any special syntax?

Tags: java, generics, compilation

```
public class Stack<E> {
    public Stack () {....}
    public void push (E e) {....}
    public E pop () {....}
    public boolean isEmpty(){....}
}

public void pushAll (Collection<E> src) {
    for (E e: src){
        push(e)
    }
}
```

I don't understand what will the problem if I'll write

```
Stack<number> numberStack = new Stack<Number>();
Collection<Integer> integers=...
numberStack.pushAll(integers);
```

Integer extends Number, so I can add a collection of Integers to `numberStack`.
But I was told that this is an error compilation- Why?

Comment: I assume that `pushAll` is actually defined *within* `Stack<E>`, right?

Comment: @Nir: Please choose a better question title. There are actually several other question here on SO with exactly the same title that ask a different things (actually, one of them asks almost exactly the same thing, so I vote to close as duplicate).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794842/generics-in-java)

Comment: @Björn: while the *reason* and *explanation* is the same, the *question* is a different one.

Comment: @Joachim: The titles match exactly, and I believe if the OP had read that question, he might not have asked this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code specified that it **only** accepts a `Collection` with the **same** type parameter as the `Stack` has.

You should write the `pushAll` method like this:

```
public void pushAll (Collection<? extends E> src)
```

This means that you expect a `Collection` of *some* type that extends `E` (i.e. you don't care what specific type it is, but it *must* be `E` or some sub-type of it).

Look at the definition of [`Collection.addAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29): it's defined in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you have two types but only one generic representation (E) so E is Number as well as Integer. Thats confusing him. You need to have the same type for the collection. Rewrite it to

```
pushAll(Collection<K> src)
```

and cast K to E.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due the fact that [collections in java are not covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Java). There are numerous question on SO about it, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184295/java-covariance-question).