# List class's toArray in Java- Why can't I convert a list of "Integer" to an "Integer" array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, toarray

I defined `List<Integer> stack = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

When I'm trying to convert it to an array in the following way:

```
Integer[] array= stack.toArray();
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to Integer[].
```

Why? It is exactly the same type- Integer to Integer. It's not like in this generic case when the classes are [father-and-son relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254820/can-i-add-to-a-generic-collection-of-type-a-values-of-type-b-which-extends-a-wi)

I tried to do casting:

```
    Integer[] array= (Integer[]) stack.toArray();
```

But here I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because of type erasure, the ArrayList does not know its generic type at runtime, so it can only give you the most general Object[]. You need to use [the other toArray method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) which allows you to specify the type of the array that you want.

```
Integer[] array= stack.toArray(new Integer[stack.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it is this:

```
Integer[] array = stack.toArray(new Integer[stack.size()]);
```

---

For the record, the reason that your code doesn't compile is not *just* type erasure.  The problem is that `List<T>.toArray()` returns an `Object[]` and it has done this before generics were introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
Integer[] array = stack.toArray(new Integer[stack.size()]);
```

We need to pass the "seed" array as an argument to the `toArray` method.