# Java Generics and Array types

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Ran into an issue with generics and array types that I am unable to solve.  It boils down to this.  In the following code, how can I convert a generic List into an Array of the same generic type, while using a factory method ("T convert(String value)") to convert each individual element of the input generic List:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    List<String> integers = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4");

    Integer[] integerArray = new TypeConverter<Integer[]>(Integer[].class).convert(integers);

    assertEquals(4, integerArray.length);
    assertEquals(1, integerArray[0].intValue());
    assertEquals(2, integerArray[1].intValue());
    assertEquals(3, integerArray[2].intValue());
    assertEquals(4, integerArray[3].intValue());
}

public class TypeConverter<T>{
    Class<T> type;

    public TypeConverter(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    T convert(List<String> values){

        List output = new ArrayList();

        for (String value : values) {
            //have to use Object.class here since I cant get the non-array type of T:
            output.add(new TypeConverter(type.getComponentType()).convert(value));
        }

        return (T) output.toArray();
    }

    T convert(String value){
        //convert to an int;
        if(type == Integer.class){
            return (T) new Integer(Integer.parseInt(value));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, my naive approach was to simply use the toArray Method, and cast the result like so:

```
(T) value.toArray()
```

but this results in a ClassCastException:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:  [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer

Is there a way to solve this that I am not seeing or should I take another approach?

**Edit**

Here's the concrete code that I am trying to fix.  Specifically the visitArray() method:

https://github.com/johncarl81/transfuse/blob/master/transfuse/src/main/java/org/androidtransfuse/analysis/adapter/AnnotationTypeValueConverterVisitor.java

Comment: possible duplicate of [List class's toArray in Java- Why can't I convert a list of "Integer" to an "Integer" array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281793/list-classs-toarray-in-java-why-cant-i-convert-a-list-of-integer-to-an-int)

Comment: I actually read that post before submitting my post.  My question is not a duplicate because I am asking about the generics related to arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the alternate version of `List.toArray` that takes as a parameter the type of the array you want to get.

[toArray Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

You may create an empty array with some method of the `Array` class.

[Array.newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29)

So having the expected type you just use `Array.newInstance(type, 0);` and pass in the result to the `toArray` method.

Edit:
Since your generic type is an array, you need to get the type of the components, try this:

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(type.getComponentType(), 0);
return (T) output.toArray(array);
```

Your value conversion method has a little something I'll let you figure out how to solve :)

Cheers!

Comment: What would I pass into the toArray() method?

Comment: return (T) output.toArray(Array.newInstance(type, 0)); doesn't compile.  Arraay.newInstance(type, 0) returns the type Object and List.toArray() requires an array type T[]

Comment: I'll create for you a sample implementation and edit the post.

Comment: There you have, you only need to fix the string to integer conversion method in order the test to pass.

Comment: Excellent +1.  This works like a charm in my example and the code I was trying to fix.  Fixed that issue in the conversion method.  Thanks Juan.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to cast to `T`, try casting to `T[]`, as you are handling an array of T's.

Comment: That is one possibility, but I was trying to aim at a more generalized solution.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest ditching the reflection and reference arrays.

Slightly abusing inheritance:

```
public abstract class StringConverter<T> {

    public List<T> convert(List<String> values) {
        List<T> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String value : values) {
            output.add(convert(value));
        }
        return output;
    }

    public abstract T convert(String value);
}

public static StringConverter<Integer> toInteger() {
    return new StringConverter<>() {
        public Integer convert(String value) {
             return Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: That's a sweet solution.  And much nicer than having to have a `convert()` routine with a big `if/else` for all the types you want to handle.

Comment: Tom, here's my problem, I don't have control over the return type of the method as I am implementing an interface.  Here's the relevant code: https://github.com/johncarl81/transfuse/blob/master/transfuse/src/main/java/org/androidtransfuse/analysis/adapter/AnnotationTypeValueConverterVisitor.java

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline what do you mean "starting from there"?  Do you have a better solution in mind?

Comment: This made me take a step back find a solution using a similar technique you described.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo().test();
    }

    public void test(){
        List<String> integers = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4");

        Integer[] integerArray = new TypeConverter<Integer>(Integer.class).convert(integers);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(integerArray));

    }

    public class TypeConverter<T>{
        Class<T> type;

        public TypeConverter(Class<T> type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        T[] convert(List<String> values){

            List<T> output = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String value : values) {
                output.add(convert(value));
            }

            return output.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(type, output.size()));
        }

        T convert(String value){
            if(type == Integer.class){
                return (T) new Integer(Integer.parseInt(value));
            }
            else if(type == Long.class){
                return (T) new Long(Long.parseLong(value));
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Very similar to what @Hidde was suggesting.

Comment: As you can see from the concrete example I added to the question, I not have control over the return type of the TypeConverter (AnnotationTypeValueConverterVisitor) as I am actually implementing an interface.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`return (T) values.toArray();` should be `return (T)output.toArray( new Integer[0])`

no, you have to hard code `new Integer[0]`

Comment: how could I do this based on the type T or Class<T> type?

Comment: java generic can't do that, you see even java api do tricks like `toArray( new Integer[0])`.

Comment: In this contrived example this hardcoded approach would work, but I require a more generalized solution.

Comment: no. the only alternate is do it like `List.toArray(T[])`. that is, pass in an array of target type..... Check the code of  `List.toArray(T[])`.