# Cast between arrays

Tags: java, casting, wicket

I need to get all children Text Field's of a container, wicket provide a method called [visitChildren](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.html#visitChildren%28java.lang.Class%29)

then I do something like:

```
(FormComponent<?>[]) visitChildren(TextField.class).toList().toArray();
```

this example doesn't work, the exception I get is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lorg.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent;
```

but if I do something like:

```
List<Component> list = visitChildren(TextField.class).toList();
FormComponent<?>[] array = new FormComponent[list.size()];
for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
    array[x] = (FormComponent<?>) list.get(x);
}
```

it work, why happen that? as far I can see both methods should work

Comment: The below method is the easy way to do it, and [this answer should](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7281807) give you an idea of why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first (broken) example is equivalent to:

```
List<Component> list = visitChildren(TextField.class).toList();
FormComponent<?>[] array = (FormComponent<?>[]) list.toArray();
```

According to to Javadoc of `toArray()`, the return type is `Object[]` but you are trying to  cast it to `(FormComponent<?>[])`, which is an illegal operation.

The tricky part is that we're not performing a cast from `Object` to `FormComponent<?>` here.

Rather, the code attempts to cast an **array** of `Object` to an **array** of `FormComponent<?>`

In order to fix this, try using the alternative `toArray` method, which takes an object of the desired return type as an argument:

```
FormComponent<?>[] array = list.toArray(new FormComponent<?>[0])
```

(Note that we're passing an empty array of `FormComponent<?>`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as a solution:

```
toArray(new FormComponent<?>[0])
```