# Getting error in variable assigning when using generics

Tags: java, generics

I have made two Lists like

```
List<LearnerEnrollment> learnerEnrollmentList = new ArrayList<LearnerEnrollment>();
List<LearnerCourseEnrollError> enrollErrorList = new ArrayList<LearnerCourseEnrollError>();
```

Then i made two Maps like

```
Map<String, List<LearnerCourseEnrollError>> courseErrorMap = new HashMap<String, List<LearnerCourseEnrollError>>();
Map<String, List<LearnerEnrollment>> courseSuccessMap = new HashMap<String, List<LearnerEnrollment>>();
```

Then i made another Map to hold the above two Maps like

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Object>>> courseMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<Object>>>();
```

Then i use the following code to add items in lists;

```
for (com.softech.vu360.lms.model.Course course : courseList) {

    Object result = getEnrollmentForCourse(customer, learner, course);

    if (result instanceof LearnerEnrollment) {
        LearnerEnrollment newEnrollment = (LearnerEnrollment)result;
        learnerEnrollmentList.add(newEnrollment);
    } else if (result instanceof String) { 
        String errorMessage = (String)result;
        LearnerCourseEnrollError enrollError = new LearnerCourseEnrollError(errorMessage, course);
        enrollErrorList.add(enrollError);       
    }       
}
```

Now i am putting values in the Map

```
courseSuccessMap.put(learner.getVu360User().getUsername(), learnerEnrollmentList);
courseErrorMap.put(learner.getVu360User().getUsername(), enrollErrorList);
courseMap.put("successfulCoursesMap", courseSuccessMap);
courseMap.put("unSuccessfulCoursesMap", courseErrorMap);

return courseMap;
```

But i am getting error at these two lines

```
courseMap.put("successfulCoursesMap", courseSuccessMap);
courseMap.put("unSuccessfulCoursesMap", courseErrorMap);
```

that

```
The method put(String, Map<String,List<Object>>) in the type
Map<String,Map<String,List<Object>>> is not applicable for the arguments 
(String, Map<String,List<LearnerEnrollment>>)

The method put(String, Map<String,List<Object>>) in the type
Map<String,Map<String,List<Object>>> is not applicable for the arguments 
(String, Map<String,List<LearnerCourseEnrollError>>)
```

Why?

My list type in the Map is `List<Object>` and `List<LearnerEnrollment>` is `List <Object>` because  `LearnerEnrollment extends Object`. Why I am getting these errors ?

If i declare my Map like this

```
Map<String, Map<String, ?>> courseMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, ?>>();
```

Then there is no error. Why i am getting error in first case?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said:

> `List<LearnerEnrollment>` is `List<Object>`

This is wrong. If it were true, you would be able to do:

```
List<<LearnerEnrollment> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> objectList = list;
objectList.add("Now what?");
```

And your type-safe list of LearnerEnrollment would suddenly contain a String.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a List in java is not covariant. A `List<LearnerEnrollment>` is not a subclass of `List<Object>`.

See [Java covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184295/java-covariance) for more information.